# .Net Asynchronous Delegate Abortion

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, asynchronous

*Background:* My application is used to execute tests using [Selenium RC](http://seleniumhq.org/projects/remote-control/) servers, and occasionally I'm running into a problem when my call to a Selenium command doesn't return the response from the RC server - it then ends up blocking the thread that is executing the test.

*Sample Code:*

```
Private Delegate Function DoCommand_Delegate(ByVal command As String, ByVal args() As String) As String
...
asyncCommand = New DoCommand_Delegate(AddressOf server.DoCommand)
asyncResult = asyncCommand.BeginInvoke(command, args, Nothing, Nothing)
Try
    ... (I have it use the AsyncWaitHandle to wait for periods of 10 seconds up to two minutes. At the end of each period it runs some checks for common problems that block Selenium from returning a response (modal dialogs) - I don't think that part is relevant to this question, it's just necessary.)
Finally
    result = asyncCommand.EndInvoke(asyncResult)
...
```

At the time `EndInvoke` is called, the worker delegate has either already finished or needs to be aborted. Most of the time it already has a response so it works just fine, but on rare occasion Selenium RC's [DoCommand](http://release.seleniumhq.org/selenium-remote-control/0.9.2/doc/dotnet/Selenium.ICommandProcessor.DoCommand.html) doesn't return, so the thread sits there locked.

**Finally, my question:** is there a resource-friendly way to abort the executing delegate, or do I need to convert it to use a manually controlled thread that can be aborted and disposed?

*Note:* This is not a question regarding Selenium, just proper multithreading.

*Note 2:* I've considered doing the following in the `Finally` before calling `EndInvoke`:

```
If Not asyncResult.IsCompleted Then asyncResult.AsyncWaitHandle.Close()
```

... But I don't know if that would actually work correctly, or what damage that could cause.

Comment: You cannot safely abort a thread.  `Thread.Abort()` is dangerous.

Comment: @SLaks: I've read a lot about the dangers of `Thread.Abort()`, so my intent is to find the best alternate solution. Leaving the thread locked is obviously the worst option and not acceptable. `DoCommand` is unmanaged code, so I don't have the option to make it self-abort when it is unable to retrieve a response from the remote server (from whatever is causing the problem). This is part of what brought me to wrap the `DoCommand` call into an async delegate in the first place. What other options are available?

Comment: There really aren't any.

Comment: I don't get the point, it is a testing framework.  Are you trying to hide a test failure under the floor mat?  What's the point about worrying about leaks in a test?

Comment: @HansPassant It's not really a test failure. The times that it has happened I can see that the failure is within either the Selenium dlls, or the Selenium RC server. Either way, the problem lies within code that I do not manage. My code needs to be able to recover from the failure, mark the test as failed, and move on with testing. If it were to do that then I could rerun any test that is effected by this freak failure and move on.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do the following at the same time:

- Abort/kill a thread non-cooperatively
- Without destroying all state associated with it (AppDomain/process)

Implies: Either terminate cooperatively (not possible here) or kill the process (AppDomain not enough because native state is involved) or don't kill the thread.

You could just not kill the thread and leave it there hanging. The rest of your program (the remaining tests) can continue to execute.

I'd not be happy to see this in production but for a test suite this could be ok (assuming the hang cannot be fixed).

Why can't a thread be aborted? This has been covered a number of times on Stack Overflow already.